# Как редактировать личные сообщения в discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

У меня присутствует бот, который должен работать на основе того что ему пишут какую-либо команду в личные сообщения, а он отправляет определенное сообщение, затем редактирует это самое сообщение, попытался сделать, в итоге получил вот такую ошибку:

```
data = await message._state.http.edit_message(message.channel.id, message.id, **fields)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понимаю код, что Вы приложили и задачу, но редактирование сообщения можно осуществить так:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    m = await ctx.send("Изначальное сообщение")

    await asyncio.sleep(2) ## добавляем задержку, чтобы увидеть изменение

    await m.edit(content="Изменённое сообщение")
```

В Вашем примере кода проблема, скорее всего, в том, что указан id сервера, а всё происходит в личном сообщении, а не на сервере.